# Can a bash or sh script see the full command that was used to call it (including pipes)?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

For example, in

```
$ myprefixprogram prog1 | prog2 | prog3
```

can `myprefixprogram` somehow see the full command string `prog1 | prog2 | prog3` and possibly modify it?

(I realise `prog1` is available via `$*` or `$@` [1])

EDIT: This would effectively be shell input preprocessing, but from within `bash`/`sh` rather than from without.

[1] http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#ARGLIST

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This sounds like something you shouldn't want to do (especially the "possibly modify it" part)

Comment: The most you really need to know about stdout is whether or not it's a TTY, which you can determine with `test -t 1`.

Comment: @bengoesboom Sometimes I like doing the naughty things.

Comment: @bengoesboom I added a more serious edit to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`| prog2 | prog3` aren't arguments to your program. This are shell redirections, that redirect stdout of the processes to stdin of the following. Only the shell knows about this.

`prog1` indeed is an argument to your program and you might modify it.

However, I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Are you?

Comment: PS: you might tell me what you want to achieve and we'll find a solution

Comment: Thanks - and I understand re arguments vs redirections. I suppose what I am aiming for here is a "preprocessor" for bash or sh to allow me to arbitrarily modify entire inputs - but within bash/sh itself! But I thought that should be another/different question, so started with this interesting (to me!) case.

Comment: Wrt preprocessing, I see this has been asked: http://superuser.com/questions/167283/is-there-a-way-to-preprocess-input-to-bash

Comment: And, more importantly, http://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command (which compares bash and zsh).

Comment: What if you start another bash: `bash "$cmd1 | $cmd2 | $cmd3"`?

Comment: Yes, indeed - "bash" there could be substituted with a preprocessor that could then call `bash`. I was wondering if the same thing could be achieved from within the same shell.

Answer (score 1):

no , shell will parse the command and set up the pipes , having said that your script can figure out child processes.